# Table sum specific column in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a trouble on how can I get the total amount column based on the status. Currently I only manage sum all of my amount column. The thing is I want to get the value of sum amount of `paid` and `unpaid` amount status, for example like the image below  the `Paid` total should `15000` and the `Unpaid` should `10000`. It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

[image]

```js
var tds = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
            var sum = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
                if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
                    sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>';
```

```html
<table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th >Status</th>
            <th >AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Paid</td>
                <td class="count-me">5000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Paid</td>
                <td class="count-me"> 5000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Unpaid</td>
                <td class="count-me">5000</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td >Unpaid</td>
                <td class="count-me">5000</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td >Paid</td>
                <td class="count-me">5000</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways. This is one of them:

```js
var tds = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
var sum = 0;
var sumPaid = 0;
var sumUnpaid = 0;
            
            for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i ++) {
                if(tds[i].className == 'count-me') {
                    sumPaid += tds[i-1].innerHTML == 'Paid' ? +tds[i].innerHTML : 0;
                    sumUnpaid += tds[i-1].innerHTML == 'Unpaid' ? +tds[i].innerHTML : 0;
                    sum += isNaN(tds[i].innerHTML) ? 0 : parseInt(tds[i].innerHTML);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sum + '</td><td>total</td></tr>';
            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sumPaid + '</td><td>total paid</td></tr>';     
            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + sumUnpaid + '</td><td>total unpaid</td></tr>';
```

```html
<table id="table">
        <tr>
            <th >Status</th>
            <th >AMOUNT</th>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Paid</td>
                <td class="count-me">5000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Paid</td>
                <td class="count-me"> 5000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Unpaid</td>
                <td class="count-me">5000</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td >Unpaid</td>
                <td class="count-me">5000</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td >Paid</td>
                <td class="count-me">5000</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I hope this is just like a homework or something. In a real application you don't do things this way. You make these kind of computations BEFORE rendering the page or using somekind of framework as a help.

I think a good advice would be for you to start learning to do things like they are done theses days with a framework like React or Angular, or even better with functional programming.

Comment: Thanks it works, Yes I've been starting learning Django framework this time.